# Debugging on real device

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to debug my app on my real android device but **AVD Manager** don't recognize my device.
 
Works that I done until now:

1- Install Google USB using **SDK Manager** 
  2- Enable **USB Debugging** on my android device 
  3- Test both of **Connect As Media Device** And **Connect As Camera** on my android device
  4- Install my device driver on *Windows* and windows can recognize my device
  5- Open *Android Device Monitor* and understand that it can recognize my device

---

Android device: ***Xperia C2305 -kitkat 4.2.2***

Android studio: ***version 2.1.2***

Comment: Install sony pc companion, drivers come with the program

Comment: It recognize by Android device Monitor but not by AVD Manager @TimCastelijns

Comment: AVD Manager is just for emulators, if you can see it in Android Device Monitor you should be able to install/run/debug/see logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> AVD Manager don't recognize my device.

It's not supposed to be there. AVD Manager is for simulators.

AVD is used when you **do not** want to run on a real device.

If you want to run on a real device, just hit the triangular green play button.